# React native ios build not working due to link error with undefined symbols from "GoogleAppMeasurement" after adding react-native-firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, linker

I'm not too sure how to fully use the XCode UI to change this or modify correctly, but I've boiled the problem down to "Other Linker Flags" using "GoogleAppMeasurement" because of Firebase/Analytics in the OTHER_LDFLAGS. The "Framework Search Paths" for GoogleAppMeasurement is pointing to the correct directory in the Pods folders but it's failing to link somehow. And I don't see the OTHER_LDFLAGS when opening .pbxproj in a regular text editor.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_objc_msgSend$initWithPattern:options:error:", referenced from:
      _APMAudienceInternalIsValidStringFilter in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAudienceStringFilter.o)
  "_objc_msgSend$initMessageInfoFn", referenced from:
      _NANOSetMessage in GoogleAppMeasurement(NANO.o)
  "_objc_msgSend$isAppActive", referenced from:
      _APMIsAppActive in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAppActive.o)
...200 more errors like this
```

Would anyone know how to get GoogleAppMeasurement to just link correctly? Sorry if this is a noob question but I've been stuck for the past 2 days to get this resolved.